# What 'function' will 'update' a post?

Tags: wp-update-post

I am using a script to import my vbulletin forum posts into wordpress as posts.

One quick issue I ran into is there are numerous forum posts with the same title 'please help me'.

When I go into the post edit screen the permalink will show 'please-help-me-2' for the second one, and 'please-help-me-3' for the third one. That is exactly what I expect.

However, when you go to **view the second one on the front end of the website**, instead of having the -2 appended to the end of the url, it simply says 'please-help-me'.

If I 'update' the post, then the permalink saves properly and the front end link changes like it should.

**What I need:**

Is there a function that I can use to go through the posts database and have it automatically 'update' all the posts so that the permalinks will change properly on the front end?

*we're talking 1.25million posts here, so automation is important.

thanks

Comment: Is wp_update_post() not the function you need? It will take a post array and update the existing post with the changed data. Although it really sounds like you need to alter your importer script to work better, frankly.

Comment: thanks Otto, exactly what I was after. You are correct, importer should rather be modified to do this right the first time instead of after the fact

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a function called wp_insert_post that takes a parameter for post ID. If the post ID is an ID that already exists, this function will update the post with the information you pass in the function parameters. I think using that function you could find a way to retrieve all of your post ID's in an array and then use a foreach loop to update each one.

Comment: You'll need to be really careful to retrieve your old post data and pass it into the parameters with your edits, though... I'd do this within a smaller scope for testing first, before risking your entire post database.

Comment: thanks for the concept. I think that as Otto said, I need to rework the importer and try it again.